# How to dispatch an action inside of an Effect

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have two Actions

1. loadAllCustomerAction //this change a loading flag to true
2. loadCustomerSuccessAction //this change a loading flag to false and has Customer[] as payload.

In my Customer Component I call

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.store.dispatch(loadAllCustomerAction());
 }
```

I want that the Effect of loadAllCustomerAction automaticly dispatch the second Action.

My Code so far

customer.actions

```
export enum ActionTypes {
   LoadAllCustomerAction = "[CUSTOMER] LOAD_CUSTOMERS",
   LoadCustomerSuccessAction = "[CUSTOMER] LOAD_CUSTOMER_SUCCESS",
}

// Load Customers ========================
export const loadAllCustomerAction = createAction(
  ActionTypes.LoadAllCustomerAction);

export const loadCustomerSuccessAction = createAction(
  ActionTypes.LoadCustomerSuccessAction,
  props<{ payload: CustomerDTO[] }>()
);
```

Reducer

```
const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,

  on(loadAllCustomerAction, (state) => ({
    ...state,
    loading: true
  })),

  on(loadCustomerSuccessAction, (state, {payload}) => ({
    ...state,
    customers: payload,
    loading:   false
  })),
...
```

Selectors

```
export const getCustomerState = createFeatureSelector<CustomerState>(
  "customers"
);

export const getCustomerLoading = createSelector(getCustomerState, state => state.loading);
export const getAllCustomers = createSelector(getCustomerState, state => state.customers);
```

My Effects

```
  constructor(private actions$: Actions,
              private customerService: CustomerService) {
  }

  loadAllCustomersActionEffect = createEffect(
    () => this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(ActionTypes.LoadAllCustomerAction),
      mergeMap(() => this.customerService.update()
        .pipe(
          map((customers: CustomerDTO[]) => (
            {
              type:    ActionTypes.LoadCustomerSuccessAction,
              payload: customers
            }
          )),
        )),
      tap(() => console.log(ActionTypes.LoadAllCustomerAction + " - Action Dispatched"))
    ),
    {dispatch: false}
  );

  loadAllCustomersActionSucessEffect = createEffect(
    () => this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(ActionTypes.LoadCustomerSuccessAction),
      tap(() => console.log(ActionTypes.LoadCustomerSuccessAction + " - Action Dispatched"))
    ),
    {dispatch: false}
  );
```

This Code fires only

```
[CUSTOMER] LOAD_CUSTOMERS - Action Dispatched
```

But I expect second action call too, what I did wrong? I Use Angular 12.2.7, ngrx 12.4.0

Comment: remove `{dispatch: false}` if you want dispatch another action

Comment: omg, thank you. I go and hanging me. Now it works

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `fromAction.yourAction(value)` and return in that action updated value.

```js
import * as fromActions from "../actions";

constructor(private actions$: Actions,
              private customerService: CustomerService) {
  }

  loadAllCustomersActionEffect = createEffect(
    () => this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(ActionTypes.LoadAllCustomerAction),
      mergeMap(() => this.customerService.update()
        .pipe(
          map((customers: CustomerDTO[]) => {
            {
              type:    ActionTypes.LoadCustomerSuccessAction,
              payload: customers
            }
            return fromActions.LoadAllCustomerActionSuccess(customers)
          }),
        )),
      tap(() => console.log(ActionTypes.LoadAllCustomerAction + " - Action Dispatched"))
    ),
    {dispatch: false}
  );
```